# Regex for yahoo email id validation in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using the yahoo external api, i need a REGEX to validate the yahoo email id.
This is my work so far...

> ^[A-Za-z0-9](\.?|_?[A-Za-z0-9]){5,}@(yahoo|ymail|rocketmail)\.com$

But this fails for localized email id's (.in, .uk etc instead of .com).
Help me out of this...

Comment: What if we substitute `\.com` part with `\.(com|in|uk)` or just `\.\w+`?

Comment: @vbo my validation not only contains in|uk, it includes all the localization :(

Comment: Without data to match against this question is not properly answerable at all. Likely there are 48 duplicates about email address regexes.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest a simpler regex like this:

```
/^[^@]+@(yahoo|ymail|rocketmail)\.com$/i
```

Assuming you are only validating `.com` email addresses otherwise use:

```
/^[^@]+@(yahoo|ymail|rocketmail)\.(com|in|co\.uk)$/i
```

Comment: my validation not only contains in|uk, it includes all the localization :(

Comment: How is localization common into this regex can you provide some examples?

Comment: If you request help with with sufficient understanding about the problem then you will better and more answers. You need to at least know some sample inputs.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer only included a few countries and Yahoo! Mail domains. Here is a more complete list, including France and Argentina:

```
/^[^@]+@(yahoo|ymail|rocketmail|yahoomail|yahooinc|aol)\.(com|[\w]{2})(\.[\w]{2})?$/i
```